# change a portion of text's color in a dropdown or checkbox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, checkbox, colors

I have a dropdown like this:

```
<select name="how-you-hear">
    <option value="---">---</option>
    <option value="Advertisement or Media">Advertisement or Media</option>
    <option value="Past Working Experience">Past Working Experience</option>
    <option value="Word Of Mouth">Word Of Mouth</option>
</select>
```

I would like to make the word Experience's color turn into yellow, so I add <span class="yellow">Experience</span>. But instead of changing the color to yellow, the span is printed just like below:

[image]

Is there another way to solve this? I have the same problem with checkboxes too.

Comment: You cannot use HTML inside an option tag. You would need a custom drop down for doing this.

Comment: No, it can not be done , similar question was asked below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651146/can-you-have-multiple-font-colors-in-select-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do, sorry!

A checkbox however, is just a checkbox. The label is a separate HTML tag that can be styled however.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='myBox' />
<label for='myBox'>This is a <span style='color:yellow;'>checkbox</span>!</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to style [checkboxes](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) if you are targeting only modern browsers. It involves hiding the checkbox itself and styling the associated label to appear as if it has a checkbox inside it.

As for selectboxes, as others have said this is not possible.